# How to create array of enum data type

Tags: database, postgresql, enums

I am trying to make a function that would work as a filter to return all places that are of certain type.

Lets say `place_types` is defined as this:

```
CREATE TYPE place_types AS ENUM ('RESTAURANT', 'MALL');
```

And my function as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  get_places(
    p_place_types place_types[],
  )
  RETURNS SETOF places_ratings
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT * FROM places_ratings
    WHERE places_ratings.place_type = ANY(p_place_types)
END $function$;
```

However `place_types[]` is producing this error:

> type bathroom_types[] does not exist

Any idea how to fix this? Is there a way without the need to create type for this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because you did not create your type in your database schema. You should try:

```
CREATE TYPE your_db_schema.place_types AS ENUM ('RESTAURANT', 'MALL');
```

and then you create your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  get_places(
    p_place_types place_types[]
  )
  RETURNS SETOF places_ratings
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT * FROM places_ratings
    WHERE places_ratings.place_type = ANY(p_place_types);
END $function$;
```

Comment: Where did I created it at then? I thought it would do it automatically since the place_types enum works just find as a column type. Thanks for answer BTW :)